# Actions on google eslint error in async/await

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, eslint, actions-on-google

I've uploaded some sample voice recordings onto the firebase cloud storage, and then I'm trying to include those recordings in the google actions speech using SSML.
but the problem I'm facing is, I'm unable to deploy the cloud function to the firebase because of eslint error, which shows up next to the async **conv** object.
and it says **Parsing error: Unexpected token conv eslint**
I'm following this medium post https://medium.com/google-developers/using-cloud-storage-for-firebase-for-hosting-rich-media-in-your-actions-a838977eb758 for the implementation but its not working.

Here's the full description of the error: 
    deploying functions
    Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

```
> functions@ lint /home/nish/Documents/Projects/Voice/functions
> eslint .


/home/nish/Documents/Projects/Voice/functions/index.js
17:44  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token conv

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nish/.npm/_logs/2019-04-02T18_17_17_639Z- 
debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

and here's the code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
const bucketAccessConfig = {
    action: "read",
    expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60
};

app.intent("Default Welcome Intent", async conv => {
    // eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define
    let intentName = "Default_Welcome_Intent";
    Path = `${intentName}/${Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1}.ogg`;
    const soundFileRef = bucket.file(Path);
    const [soundUrl] = await soundFileRef.getSignedUrl(bucketAccessConfig);
    // console.log(Path);
    // console.log(storage);
    conv.ask(`<speak><audio src=${soundUrl}/></speak>`);
});
```

Comment: Which version of Node are you using? You may need to check your package.json.

Comment: `"engines": {
        "node": "8"
    },`

node version 8

Comment: Depending on your eslint configuration, maybe you need to wrap the function arguments, ie: `app.intent("Default Welcome Intent", async (conv) => {`